# C-Pre-Processor macros order

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I just followed a tutorial that involved doing CPP macros to implement a Debug system in a program. One great behavior of the macros is being recursive, making it possible to put a macro inside another macro like below:

```
#define MACRO1 "World"
#define MACRO2 printf("Hello %s\n",MACRO1);
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MACRO2
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `Hello World`

The below also seems to work:

```
#define MACRO2 printf("Hello %s\n",MACRO1);
#define MACRO1 "World"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MACRO2
    return 0;
}
```

So just to understand, does CPP first reads all `#define X` to make a list of declared macros, to then substitute the macros that are inside other macros, avoiding the "chicken and egg" issue on pre-processing?

I think that makes sense, considering pre-processing is a one-time only process (during compilation), not happening in real time. So it shouldn't matter where in the code a macro was defined, but actually if it was defined at all.

Having a 3000 lines code and only in the last line defining a macro used in the code would be valid then?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many passes does the C preprocessor make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442028/how-many-passes-does-the-c-preprocessor-make)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually happens is that the recursive substitution happens only when a macro is used, not when it's defined.

So at

```
#define MACRO2 printf("Hello %s\n",MACRO1);
```

the preprocessor just memorizes that `MACRO2` expands as the 7 tokens `printf`, `(`, `"Hello %s\n"`, `,`, `MACRO1`, `)`, and `;`.  At this point it doesn't care which if any of those tokens are macros.

At the point in `main` where you do

```
MACRO2
```

the preprocessor expands the macro to those seven tokens, and then checks to see whether the token stream contains any more macros that can be expanded again.  It notices `MACRO1` and substitutes the token `"World"`.  At this point it checks again, but there are no more macros for expansion.

You'll still run into problems if you try to use a macro before it's been `#define`d.