# C++ Macro containing #ifdef

Tags: c++, linux, macros

I am trying to define a C++ macro that contains an `#ifdef`. However, the preprocessor complains that it expects an expression when I use `PRINT_PRETTY_FUNCTION`.

```
#define PRINT_PRETTY_FUNCTION \
    #ifdef PRINT_FUNC_NAMES \
    printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); \
    #endif
```

Does C++ allow for such a macro definition?

Answer (score 0):

`#ifdef` should be first in its line. It is not in your case.

These are directives to the pre-processor which only does one pass evaluating the macro (once expanded the preprocessor won't look at it again), so you just can't do what you're trying to do.

Also see this [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442057/618400).

Comment: I wanted the compiler to just replace `PRINT_PRETTY_FUNCTION` with the `#ifdef`.

Comment: That's the thing - it's not the compiler that's doing the replacing, it's the preprocessor.

Comment: I am so sorry, you're absolutely right. I meant the preprocessor.

Comment: So preprocessor directives have to be on their own lines, you can't have two different directives on the same line.